# iOS 8.3: Alert View Cancel Button not responding in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, appdelegate, ios8.3

I am working on my project in iOS 8.3 in Xcode 6.3.2, I have placed an `AlertView` in `AppDelegate` class when my web service returns error, but when I am trying to click cancel button on Simulator, it is not responding. Does anyone facing same error?

Below is my code:

```
UIAlertView *alertFailure = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Occured" message:@"Something went wrong" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alertFailure show];
```

**Edit 1: Added Delegate Method on request**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // the user clicked OK
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    // do something here...
    alertView.hidden = YES;
}
}
```

**Edit 2: It is not even sensing the delegate**

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Hi, Rajat. I have tried, but tell me which delegate method you are using, is it  -(void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView{

Comment: If you are using above method it will not call during the button click.

Comment: clickedButtonAtIndex method will call

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan: Tried not working

Comment: I have tried  tried your code in appDelegate , its working fine. No need to attach delegate . There might be some other issue , post your code  for error where you showing alertView

Comment: Remove the line     alertView.hidden = YES;
 then try

Comment: @ArpitParekh Then what to write there?

Comment: Nothing. why do you want to hide alert view ? It is its behavious that it will close automatically on button click.

Comment: @ArpitParekh: Buddy but its not responding to anything...

Comment: If you're targeting 8.3 you should use UIAlertController, UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8

Comment: No, my targets are iOS7 & 8

Comment: working fine in xcode 6.3.2 and ios 8 .

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan If we use this in delegate methods of App Delegate, it is working fine, but if we use it in any other method in app delegate it is not working.

Comment: can you share the method from where you are showing alert ?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't already, you need to add that the `AppDelegate` is conforming to `UIAlertViewDelegate` like this:

In `AppDelegate.h`:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

**Edit:** I just created an [empty project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/185344/StackOverflow/AlertTest.zip) and pasted your code in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, and it worked. No delegate methods, no nothing. Maybe remove the whole `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method?

**Edit 2:** If you're only targeting iOS 8+, then you can (and should, since `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8) use the new `UIAlertController`:

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error Occurred"
                                                               message:@"Something went wrong."
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh Can you add to your post the delegate method code?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh Check my edit, download the test project if you want.

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh Did you try removing your delegate method?

Comment: Yes, I implemented first like that only

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh Edited answer, if you're targeting iOS 8+

Comment: No, my targets are iOS7 & 8

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the following delegate method in your application.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Here whenever you will click on the Cancel Button then it will work without any problem. As seems that you have already set the delegate for UIAlertView.

Please let me know if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting iOS 8.3 you can use UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView, you don't need to implement any protocols or set a delegate, just use an action:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error Occured"
                                                               message:@"Something went wrong"
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                               handler:NULL];

[alert addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:alert
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```